# Licence for paid extension when creating extension

Tags: extensions, magento-connect, licensing

I created an extension that i want to put in magento commerce. I am looking for a licence for paid extension which doesn't give the rights to the buyer to distribute it further (the buyer can use it as many times as he wants but not give it to someone else).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a great website for that: https://tldrlegal.com/.
Visit the [browse page](https://tldrlegal.com/licenses/browse) and click on "License by conditions"

It explains the types of licenses very well. And it looks like you need at [Agate License](https://tldrlegal.com/license/agate-license)

You can add the license by adding a `LICENSE.txt` file with the full text to the module files and adding the below comment to each file in your module

```
/**
 * [Module name] extension
 * 
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 * 
 * This source file is subject to the Agate License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://tldrlegal.com/license/agate-license#fulltext
 * 
 * @category       [Namespace]
 * @package        [Module]
 * @copyright      Copyright (c) 2015
 * @license        https://tldrlegal.com/license/agate-license#fulltext Agate License
 */
```

Comment: thank you! can i just use it like this i write in my magento create extension Agate License with a link to https://tldrlegal.com/license/agate-license#fulltext?

Comment: Updated my answer :)